# Convert Array[AnyVal] to primitive Array[T], T can be Int, Double and etc in scala

Tags: scala

I learnt that in scala `Array` is not a convariant collection. If I have an array of `AnyVal`, and all elements in array has the same type, how can I make it an array of primitives?

I am think to use the first element of the array like to detect the data type. Like the code below:

```
def convert(arr:Array[AnyVal]):Array[_] = {
  val firstElement = arr.head
  firstElement match {
    case y:Int => ???
    case y:Long => ???
    case y:Float => ???
    case y:Double => ???
     ... 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type of a function is defined at compile time. You can't change the return type of a function based on data that is passed to the function.

The type of a value is also defined at compile time at the point where it is created. However that value can be held in a variable of any supertype of the value type, which is what makes the type system so powerful. Scala also makes it easy to tell the actual type of a value by using pattern matching.

If you know the type you want at compile time, use `collect` to narrow the type of a value using pattern matching. For example, to get an list of `Double` from a list of `AnyVal` do this:

```
val doubles: List[Double] = anyList.collect{ case d: Double => d }
```

Any non-`Double` values will be discarded.

Also note that `Array` is a Java hang-over, so prefer Scala types like `List` or `Vector`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is an optimal solution (or for that matter the idea of taking AnyVals input, and converting them to primitives). But typecasting all elements to the desired type should work. Here is a snippet I just tried out.

```
  def convert(ar: Array[AnyVal]): Array[_] = {
    ar.head match {
      case y: Int => ar.map(_.asInstanceOf[Int])
      case y: Long => ar.map(_.asInstanceOf[Long])
      case _ => Array() // do check if this can be the case
    }
  }
```